# Problems calling C++ DLLs in Delphi

Tags: c, delphi, labview

I'm having some problems calling C++ DLLs in delphi, the DLLs are written in Labview but the DLL syntax is all C++, I think the main issue is to do with trying to pass data to the function as a dynamic array of double (which is inherently a pointer right?)

the function definition in the.h header file is:

```
int16_t __cdecl NRELIVparExtract(
  double voltageV[], 
  double currentA[], 
  int32_t nDataPoints, 
  uint16_t fitAlgorithim, 
  int16_t *twoOrLessPoints, 
  double *Voc, 
  double *Isc, 
  double *Vmp, 
  double *Imp
);
```

My delphi code i'm trying to use to call it is:

```
public   { Public declarations }
end;

 var
    Function NRELIVparExtract (voltageV, currentA: Array of Double; nDataPoints :Integer;
            fitAlgorithim :Word; Var twoOrLessPoints : SmallInt;
       Voc, Isc, Vmp, Imp : Double): smallint ; CDecl;External IVparExtract_NREL.dll'
```

blah

```
procedure TFormMainIVanalysis.ExtractNREL(InputFileName : ShortString);
var
  VoltArray, CurrArray : Array Of double;
  blah
Begin

  NRELresult := NRELIVparExtract(VoltArray,CurrArray,NpointsForFitting, fitAlgorithm,     twoOrLessPoints, LVoc, LISc, LVmpp, LImpp);
```

I variously get either an access violation error when the compiler gets to the begin line in my delphi .dpr OR I get IVparExtract_NREL.dll not found

any suggestions very welcome, cheers, Brian

Comment: Aren't you missing something to say that the doubles at the end of the function are pointers?

Comment: ah... we might have found the fix.. we put the full path in after external like this   External 'E:\blah\IVparExtract_NREL.dll'  now it seems to find the DLL but we now just have to install the NI labview runtime engine...

Comment: Also be aware that LabVIEW doubles are big endian, while Win platforms are little endian

Comment: You mean LabView double-float values are not C double/float compatible?

Comment: The utility 'HeadConv'(http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26451) may help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C type `double[]` does *not* translate to the Delphi type `array of Double`. The Delphi type is an *open array*, which actually translates to *two* parameters internally, a pointer to the first element, and an integer holding one less than the number of elements in the array. Instead, you should do as C does, and "decay" the array to a simple pointer.

The C type `double*` does not translate to the Delphi type `Double`. It's a pointer, so declare your parameter types as pointers.

That should give you the following declaration:

```pascal
function NRELIVparExtract(voltageV, currentA: PDouble; nDataPoints: Integer;
    fitAlgorithim: Word; var twoOrLessPoints: SmallInt;
    Voc, Isc, Vmp, Imp: PDouble): SmallInt; cdecl;
    external 'IVparExtract_NREL.dll';
```

If your program cannot find the DLL, then you should make sure that your DLL lives in a place where the OS will look for it, such as your program's directory, or somewhere on the system path. [MSDN has the details on the library search order.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx)

Comment: The official way to translate `double *` is to make it a var parameter, i.e. `var Voc, Isc, Vmp, Imp: Double`, but translating pointers to pointers is IMO easier to understand. +1

Comment: @Rudy There is no official way. If `NULL` is a legal value then you need to declare the parameter to be a pointer. Otherwise `var` is reasonable. Since these are arrays I think, `var` makes no real sense and passing a pointer to the first element is the right way to declare it.

Comment: @david: There certainly is an official way. You are right about the rule that if something can be NULL or denotes an array, it should not be declared var. But I don't think these are arrays, they are problably return values. But as I said, I personally prefer to stay closer to the original, so I would use PDouble anyway.

Comment: @david: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10281 is the official conversion spec. It is very old and was written by Chralie Calvert when he was still at Borland, sometime around the D6 timeframe, IIRC. Conversions by Embarcadero and JEDI are still done according to that spec.

Comment: @Rudy, that says to use `var` or pointers as appropriate, depending on whether the parameter can be null. But I think the default, in the absence of better knowledge, should be to use pointers. Although it might not be the *ideal* translation type, you can never go *wrong* using pointers.

Comment: @Rudy OK, what I meant is that there is no one single official way to convert double*. In fact I was looking at the two arrays. I agree that the final 4 params could well be scalar return values and then you simply need to apply the "can you pass NULL" rule.

Comment: Both: I agre that using pointers is the best approach anyway, since it is what the user sees in C too. If sometimes var is used, and some other times it isn't, you must always look at the sources (or trust the editor) to see if it is translated with var or not. Consistently translating pointers in C as pointers in Delphi is, IMO, preferrable. Marcel van Brakel did this in his rather complete API conversion suite. But it is not Borland/etc. policy.